# is it possible to have different colors of text in a textbox or listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, colors

I'm not sure if it's possible. I wrote a code like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + countu.ToString().Trim() + " u's");
listBox1.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Violet;

listBox1.Items.Add("There are " + j.ToString().Trim() + " vowels");
listBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

When I executed this code, the color of the texts were blue. I would like to have it first "violet" and then the next line of code blue. Is it possible?

Cheers

Comment: How about re-tagging to include the specific language? That way anyone actively looking for the language will see the question. I'd do it myself, but I don't (to my *shame*) recognise it...I am *such* a neophyte to this programming thing.

Comment: It looks like C#/WinForms but we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: oopss my bad, its C# WinForms. I already edited my post. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an owner-drawn listbox as described in MSDN here:

> [**How to: Create an Owner-Drawn List Box**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229679.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/), though it's not exactly a `ListBox`, allows to do that. If you want `ListBox` only, see [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sahuja/OwnerDrawListBox11212005014826AM/OwnerDrawListBox.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only if you draw everything your-self (owner-drawn).

Answer (score 0):

Try using listBox1.Items[currentItem].Attributes.CssStyle to set the color of each item on a granular level.

e: whoops, missed the windows-forms tag. my bad.